# Use 'MediaWiki UI' or 'Bootstrap3' styles in all the forms of Mediawiki

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I am working on my own Mediawiki installation and developed a skin based on Bootstrap 3 ([MediaWikiBootstrap](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Skin:MediaWikiBootstrap)). There are a few issues which are taking time to resolve and few cases i am not sure how to resolve.

I used ContactPage extension and could not find an easy way to use bootstrap form css classes. there are options to use 'MediaWiki UI' for that contact form but i am facing the same problem with the other pages, like the All articles, search page and so on.

so is there any way to use 'MediaWiki UI' in all the form and can i create my own form style using Bootstrap3 css classes?

Answer (score 1):

There is a configuration variable ([$wgUseMediaWikiUIEverywhere](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUseMediaWikiUIEverywhere)) which, if set to true, should activate mediawiki ui on every form element (that is build with the Html or Xml MediaWiki class) in MediaWiki (excluding forms build with string operations).

For the long term it is planned to remove this variable an activate mediawiki ui by default.

If i understand Bootstrap correctly, there is no easy way to add/remove classes to elements generated by MediaWiki.

Btw: There is already a bootstrap skin, maybe you can reuse this? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Skin:BootStrapSkin

Comment: $wgUseMediaWikiUIEverywhere worked for many of the pages but not in all pages, like it did not work here http://en.banglapedia.org/index.php?title=Special:AllPages

Comment: Unfortunately yes. That's one of the pages, that build the form itself (partially): https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/master/includes/specials/SpecialAllPages.php#L103-L149 It's one of the pages on the list, that needs to be fixed: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T72913

Comment: i did not checked all the form pages, but do you know any other pages? can you tell me how can i use Bootstrap classes here?

Comment: At least any page listed in the "Blocked by" section of https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T72913 I don't know a standard way adding specific classes to specific type of elements, that's the problem we're trying to fix with the linked task ;) Like i said: Maybe you can look at the code of the linked bootstrap skin to see, how they solved the problem. Maybe you can style the elements without css classes?